# View the size of my ScriptDB, not how many objects..but the size of the database

Tags: google-apps-script

The Question should be clear enough. I would like to know if there is a way to view the size of my ScriptDB?  If I call the method .getSize() it will produce the number of items in my database?

I would like to know the size as I would like to be able to set up a script to go and delete old entries as I approach the 200mb size limit.

Thanks so much in advance for your time and energy.

Comment: Ok, It looks like there is another thread regarding this same issue called: "ScriptDb remaining quota" Unfortunately the answer is: This feature isn't currently available. The Apps Script team is looking to make this data available via the quota dashboard sometime in one of the next few releases.

If you need access to this programmatically, it'd be a good idea to file a feature request in our issues tracker"    SO, I will be filing a feature request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is written in the 1st comment of the question, now is impossible to get a ScriptDB data size but there is a workaround for this problem. The workaround is to envelope DB handling code by `try/catch` and clean the db if the code throws an exception. See an example bellow

```
try {
  db.save(...);
}
catch(err) {
  // scavenge here
}
```

In the same way is possible to handle quota limits exceptions of the [Cache Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_cacheservice).